# VSCode programatically search and replace in an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to execute a command in my extension to search for some word in all files in the workspace (workspace contains more than 15k files) and then replace that word with something else, but I don't find any VSCode API for that kind of thing.

Do you guys maybe know if there's some command for that?

Answer (score 3):

I have expanded an extension I wrote that does what you want with user-defined commands for search and replace.  See [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).  It basically builds the arguments for the `workbench.action.findInFiles` command as used below.  Too much code to show here, but have a look at the [repository](https://github.com/ArturoDent/find-and-transform), particularly `search.js`.

---

In an extension, you can do this:

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.findInFiles',
  {
    query: "customCommentHowdy",   // arguments to the findInFiles command
    replace: "that's so swell",
    triggerSearch: true,
    preserveCase: true,
    useExcludeSettingsAndIgnoreFiles: true,
    isRegex: false,
    isCaseSensitive: true,
    matchWholeWord: true,
    filesToInclude: "",
    filesToExclude: "./*.css"
  }).then(() => {                      // this command just returns 'undefined'
    setTimeout(() => {
      vscode.commands.executeCommand('search.action.replaceAll');
    }, 1000);
});
```

I couldn't get it to trigger the `replaceAll` without the delay - with 15k files you may have to increase that a bit.  `Async/await` didn't seem to help either.

You will still get the confirmation box about actually doing the `replace`, I don't think that can be avoided.

If you didn't put the `search.action.replaceAll` command in there then the user would have to hit the `replaceAll` button themselves (and then verify that really do want to do the replace).

The Search panel will appear and be focused when you do this.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way in VS Code extension to get the result of a file search in the extension's code directly so you can process it and do some other stuff?

Comment: @vbgd I don't think there is any way to do that if you mean across files.  You could do that in a file though.  I believe there is a  proposed api that will someday do what you want, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.findTextInFiles.d.ts, but that isn't moving very fast.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it looks like that proposal is exectly what I would need.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a Macro. You'd code it to open each file in turn, search + replace the text and then save the file.

Something like VSCode Macros:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EXCEEDSYSTEM.vscode-macros