# Visual Studio Code: Find and replace specific text programmatically by using an Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Let me start by saying I don't have a good understanding of Typescript/javacript, but I use VSC on a daily basis and want to use it to search and replace some text, let's say 'sqlstatement' and replace it by another text, eg 'SQL_Statement' .

I can replace a selection if I select it manually:

```
const selection = editor.selection;
editor.edit(editBuilder => {editBuilder.replace(selection, "SQL_Statement");
```

But I would like to find the "sqlstatement" text by using code, but don't know how.

If there are other options which lead to the same result that would be fine also I guess.
Things I tried are:

```
let text = editor.document.getText();
text1 = text.replace("sqlstatement","SQL_Statement");
```

This works for replacing the string, but in this case I don't know how to reapply this 'text1' to the document.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66112468/836330 (essentially a duplicate) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65650413/836330 for a way to trigger the replacement.

Comment: @Mark, Thank you, I will try to transform it to my extension. Can't see why I didn't find these when I was searching for a solution last weeks. But thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct the `vscode.Range` of the text you want to replace. And use this `Range` in an `EditBuilder` you get from the `editor`.

Find the character positions `start` and `end` in the document text, and transform this location to a line-character `Position` (`editor.document.positionAt(offset)`) and with these 2 `Position`s build a `Range`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, if only I knew how to get the range of the text I want to replace. I know that in my example the "selection"  is a range, but that is because I manually selected the "selection".
In all examples I found I see people talking about the necessary range, but cannot find a way to determine the range where my "sqlstatement" text is located. And I think I spend many many hours searching for a soluton.

Comment: @mrpalferink Read the second paragraph

Comment: It must be my limited understanding of coding, but when you say " Find the character positions start and end in the document text" , how do I automatically find the spot in the open document where the word "sqlstatement" is positioned?
Once I have found it, I think I will be able to get the range and replace the text.

Comment: @mrpalferink how do you search a word in a string?

Comment: That is the issue here I guess, I don't know how to do that.
I am using this code now, which does what it should do, but seems like shooting a canon to kill a fly :-| . It sets the entire document text in a string, replace something in this string and sending the string back to the document by replacing all text. 
But it would be nice to get the exact position/range of the string I want to replace and just replace that piece.

Comment: This works, as stated above:
let text = document.getText();
let text1 = text.replace("sql", "_SQL_");

let invalidRange = new vscode.Range(0, 0, document.lineCount /*intentionally missing the '-1' */, 0);
let fullRange = document.validateRange(invalidRange);

editor.edit(editBuilder => {
    editBuilder.replace(fullRange, text1);
});

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and got it figured.
If I got your question right, you want to replace all occurrences of "sqlstatement"s with "SQL_Statement"s.

You need to use regex.

```js
const textEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
if (!textEditor) {
  vscode.window.showErrorMessage("Editor Does Not Exist");
  return;
}

let fullText = editor.document.getText();
// 'g' flag is for global search & 'm' flag is for multiline.
const regex = /sqlstatement/gm; 
//searching for previously declared 'sqlstatement' in regex and replacing it with 'SQL_Statement'.
let textReplace = fullText.replace(regex, `SQL_Statement`);
let invalidRange = new vscode.Range(0, 0, editor.document.lineCount, 0);
let validFullRange = editor.document.validateRange(invalidRange);

  editor.edit(editBuilder => {
    editBuilder.replace(validFullRange, textReplace);
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Regexp `g` flag is for global search to match all occurrences, without it, it'll only check for the first.

Regexp `m` flag is for multiline, it makes `^` and `$` match at line beginnings and line endings(instead of at string), respectively.

Reference: [global - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)  ,
[multiline - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline)